# making a specific title for my page

Tags: tables, titles, tabularx

I'm trying to create a title for my page like this:
[image]
I used this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multirow}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ YYY }
  \toprule
  \toprule
  \rowcolor{light-gray}

  somthing & &  something  \\
  \rowcolor{light-gray}
 something & \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/KNTU.pdf}&  something   \\
    \rowcolor{light-gray}
 something && something    \\
  \bottomrule
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

and i got this:

[image]

I can't figure out whats wrong!!

Answer (score 2):

That is because `\includegraphics` lays the bottom of image on the baseline. A `\raisebox{-0.5\height}` does the trick. It's harder to add vertical spacing between top and bottom rules, because of the coloured rows. The simplest is to add a horizontal rule with the desired height,of width `\textwidth`, and with the same colour as the rows background. In the following code I added rules 10pt high under the top rules and above the bottomrules.

I added some improvements to the rest of your code:  using booktabs with colors in cells or rows results in small white strips at the top and the bottom of cells, a consequence of the `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` vertical spaces added around rules. I managed to compensate for this difficulty.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multirow, boldline}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{light-gray}{Lavender!60!}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYY }
  \toprule
\noalign{\vspace*{-1pt}}
  \hlineB{2}
\noalign{\textcolor{light-gray}{\rule{\textwidth}{10pt}}}
\rowcolor{light-gray} something & & something \\
  \rowcolor{light-gray}
 something & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{euclid}}& something \\
    \rowcolor{light-gray}
 something && something \\
\noalign{\textcolor{light-gray}{\rule{\textwidth}{10pt}}}
\addlinespace[-\aboverulesep]
  \bottomrule
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the question's title, the OP wants this on the top of the first page, so a `table` environment doesn't seem the best solution.

Comment: I didn't notice it. I'll remove the environment. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. How can I create a space between my text and top and bottom line??

Comment: Do you mean between the text in the table, and the top and the bottom lines? I've added a way to do that. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The table is just right, the middle somethings are aligned to the bottom vertically. One way of solving this is using the array definition of `m{1.75in}`. Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multirow}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.75in}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ YYY }
            \toprule
            \toprule
            \rowcolor{light-gray}

            somthing & &  something  \\
            \rowcolor{light-gray}
            something & \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}&  something   \\
            \rowcolor{light-gray}
            something && something    \\
            \bottomrule
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}



\end{document}
```

Of course any other vertical alignment to the center would work as a solution.